# How can we obtain an algebraic expression for $\tilde{D}_{R}(p)$? (Peskin's Quantum field theory, p.30)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

I'm reading the Peskin's Introduction to quantum field theory, p.30 and stuck at some statement.

As in the page 30, let $D_R(x-y)$ be the retarded Green's function. Note that the retarded Green's function satisfies $$(\partial^2 + m^2)D_{R}(x=y)=-i\delta^{4}(x-y).\tag{2.56}$$ And in the page, the authors said that:

> If we had not already derived expression (2.54), we could find it by Fourier transformation. Writing
> \begin{equation} D_R(x-y)=\int\frac{d^{4}p}{(2\pi)^{4}}e^{-ip \cdot (x-y)}\tilde{D}_{R}(p),\tag{2.57}
> \end{equation}
> we obtain an algebraic expression for $\tilde{D}_{R}(p)$:
> $$ (-p^{2}+m^{2})\tilde{D}_{R}(p)=-i.$$

And I can't understand why/how this algebraic relation is derivable. By the inverse fourier transform? By taking $(\partial^{2} +m^{2})$ to either sides of (2.57)? Can anyone helps or hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the left-hand-side$$\left(\partial^2 +m^2 \right) D_R(x-y) = \left( \partial^2 + m^2 \right) \int \! \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-ip(x-y)} \tilde{D}_R(p)$$ $$=\int \! \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-ip(x-y)}(-p^2 +m^2) \tilde{D}_R(p)$$ and the right-hand-side $$-i \delta^{(4)}(x-y)= -i \int  \! \frac{d^4 p}{(2 \pi)^4}e^{-ip(x-y)} $$ of $\left( \partial^2 + m^2\right) D_R(x-y) = -i \delta^{(4)} (x-y)$, leading to the desired result.

Comment: Wow, such a technique! Thank you very much~

Answer (score 1):

Act with $-p^2+m^2$ on (1). In the RHS bring it under the integral and you can replace $-p^2$ by $\partial^2$ and there you go.

Comment: Thank you. $p$ is the integral variable. How can the passage of $-p^{2} +m^{2}$ to the integral sign be possible? Uhm..and why can we replace $-p^{2}$ by $\partial^{2}$?

Comment: @Plantation $\partial_\mu e^{-ipx}= -i p_\mu e^{-ipx}$

Comment: @Plantation Seriously? I have to answer that? replace $p$ by $q$ as integration variable and then use the delta function to integrate $q$ out.